# 'This view is not constrained.' error though view is constrained with circular positioning in android-constraintlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am using constraintlayout's circular positioning in my layout. But Android Studio IDE shows me this error.

My center item:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/centerImageView"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/xml_white_circle_stroke_bg"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV4"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineV3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_ic_girl" />
```

Constrained item:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/noteImageView"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_ic_notes"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:background="@drawable/vector_item_home_bg"
            app:layout_constraintCircle="@+id/centerImageView"
            app:layout_constraintCircleAngle="0"
            app:layout_constraintCircleRadius="100dp" />
```

But code runs as expected. So how can I prevent this error?

Comment: can you show your full XML page please?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990/6296561

Comment: @TamirAbutbul code I added in my question with parent <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guidelineH3">
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>